# Which escape attempt was "a bit of a fiasco" in Chicken Run?

Tags: chicken-run

In the opening scene of *Chicken Run*, we see a number of escape attempts. Later, when they are planning the 'chicken cannon-ball' escape (that never happens) Ginger says that the last attempt was "a bit of a fiasco", to which two heavily bandaged chickens look together as if to say "a bit?".

My question is whether this is referring to one of the introductory attempts, and if so which one?

Comment: Isn't this simply a joke in and of itself? (Further) establishing the profusion of escape attempts and their recurrent failure.

Comment: Possibly. I don't know.

Comment: Maybe a [noodle incident](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident)?